# How to get the index value of the row above and below in Pandas idxmax()

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
max_index = df.A.idxmax()
```

What I am trying to do is get the index value right above and below `max_index` in the dataframe. Could you please advise how this could be accomplished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're unsure whether the index has duplicates, a safe way is:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.util.testing.makeDataFrame()
max_index = df.A.idxmax()
before = df['A'].shift(-1).idxmax()
after = df['A'].shift().idxmax()
```

If the indices are unique:

```
i = df.index.get_loc(max_index)
before, after = df.index[i-1], df.index[i+1]
```

Or, maybe slightly more efficient and which also handles duplicated indices:

```
i = df.reset_index()['A'].idxmax()
before, max_index, after = df.index[i-1:i+2]
```